# Error while setting up cron job?

Tags: unix, cron

I want schedule the cron job on every Monday and Thursday at 1.00 AM. I have used below command but I am getting an error.

0 1 * * Mon,Thu /home/abc/xyz.ksh

crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated.

Can anyone advise me how to set it up?

Comment: What does the entire crontab look like? What line does it complain about?

Comment: @DarkFalcon:- There is only one line in crontab. I mentioned it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0 1 * * 1,4 /home/abc/xyz.ksh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Where 1 and 4 translates to Monday and Thursday respectively. Valid range is 0 to 6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 representing Saturday

Answer (score 2):

Please try this instead:

```
0 1 * * 1,2 /home/abc/xyz.ksh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks Santiago. Can you please help me what are numbers for Monday and Thursday. 1 is for sunday or monday?

Comment: I believe the correct answer is this - `0 1 * * 1,4 /home/abc/xyz.ksh >/dev/null 2>&1` where 1 is Monday and 4 is Thursday

Comment: @Vicky could be, as long as you don't end up doing it on a Tuesday(2) rather than a Thursday(4) :-)